# Can I compare hard drive folder and git project code

Tags: windows, git, gitlab

I am new to Git. I been given the physical current source code for a system. I also have the git project. It is possible that the git project has not been kept up to date and does not reflect what is in the folder.

I am using windows.

The source is in `c:\src\myapp`

The git project is `https://gitlab.../myapp`

The git code is in `master`

Is there a way to compare my hard drive copy to git project? Do I need to extract the git copy to another hard drive folder?

Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One** way (and I'm sure there are others as well) you could go about this is to `git clone` your gitlab "myapp" into a temporary directory and then just move the `.git` folder into `c:\src\myapp`. That way git will tell you all of the *possible* differences between the remote and the local project.

```
git clone https://gitlab.... tempmyapp
mv tempmyapp/.git myapp/.git
rm -r tempmyapp
```

*note:* maybe for windows the commands will be different, but you can achieve the same through the GUI.

---

If you then don't need the `.git` folder in `myapp` you can later remove it.